# what is use of question mark '?' in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain

In solidity I came across a code `uint256 q = p % 2 != 0 ? a : b;` what does it mean ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a regular *inline if* statement, found in many modern languages.

It means "set the value `q` to be either `a` or `b` - decided whether `p % 2 != 0` gives `true` or `false`.

This can be rewritten as:

```
uint256 q;
if (p % 2 != 0) {
  q = a;
}
else {
  q = b;
}
```

Comment: It's called the "ternary operator", "conditional operator" or "inline if", not "if and only if"

Comment: Cheers, fixed. *If and only if* comes from one not-so-modern language long time ago...